# Is it possible to transfer my local installation entirely to the server?

Tags: migration

I just finished my blog I made locally and I would like to upload it to the server as it is in my computer, including the posts and the plugins. Is it possible to do it?

I already have a WordPress installation in my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of methods you can try. Depending on whether you want to keep your online data or not.

## Export Tool

There is a tool for exporting data from one installation to another, under the Tools menu. Head over to `Tools > Export` and select `All content` from the options. Click the `Download Export File` and save it.

Now, head over to `Tools > Import` in your published blog. Choose the file you saved from the last step, and import your content into the online blog.

## Manual Transfer

You can also copy your entire WordPress directory via FTP, and then change the `WordPress Address (URL)` & `Site Address (URL)` in the settings from `localhost` to `http://example.com`. This however will override your existing content, but your plugins and themes will be uploaded too.

## Plugins

To transfer the plugins, simply copy them to your online server via FTP, and activate them from the plugins menu. Their settings will not be preserved, but some plugins themselves offer exporting their data. You may however be able to copy their data from your local database to your online database.

Answer (score 0):

I use the excellent WP-Clone plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/ .

You install it on the source and do a backup. Then install it on the target system (at your host), which has a WP install. Restore it via the URL you saved on the backup.

Ta-Da!  Everything is moved and adjusted for the new site. You'll need to log in with your source credentials. But everything is there with no mess.  (I sometimes get a failure on the first restore, but the second one works just fine.)

Best way I know (and use) to move a site from one place to another.